# React Native Android assembleRelease - Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-twitter-signin

I have this problem when running `./gradlew assembleRelease`

```
Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: Duplicate module name:
react-native Paths: 
/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with 
/node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/node_modules/react-native/package.json
```

`./gradlew assembleDebug` works just fine.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I've spent like 4 hours reading github threads and none of the options seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package using the code in the `master` branch.
`npm install --save GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin#master`

since the fix has been added to `master` but hasn't been published to `npm` yet.

The issue is due to duplicate dependencies in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0"
 },
```